# Apply for a Russian visa in English in Strasbourg

Tags: visas, russia, consulates

I am travelling to Russia and need a visa. My nearest Russian consulate is in Strasbourg, but I don't speak French or Russian. Will I be able to make my application there?

I live near Strasbourg but in Germany, if that makes a difference; I'm not an EU citizen.

Comment: The language is not the only problem, living in Germany might indeed make a difference. For Russia, people often go through some agent, it costs something but makes the process relatively painless (in my experience) and might take care of the language issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the website of the Russian consulate in Germany](http://russische-botschaft.de/konsularabteilung.html), German residents must apply for a visa in a particular visa application center, depending on which state they live in:

- Berlin: Berlin, Brandenburg, Saxony-Anhalt, Mecklenburg-Vorpommern.
- Bonn: North-Rhine-Westphalia, Rhineland-Palatinate, Saarland.
- Frankfurt am Main: Baden-Württemberg, Hesse.
- Hamburg: Bremen, Hamburg, Lower Saxony, Schleswig-Holstein.
- Leipzig: Saxony, Thuringia.
- Munich: Bavaria.

A friend of mine went to the "wrong" visa centre and was told this was not allowed, but in the end was allowed to submit her application.

Answer (score 3):

Through the consular website in Strasbourg I ended up on [this page](http://visa.kdmid.ru) to fill in the application either in English or Russian, so it seems they accept them in English. The websites you can have translated through the browser or Google translate. But I suspect in dealing with the consulate staff you might need to understand some French or Russian.

[consular website](http://www.strasbourg.mid.ru/) -> [French visa service](http://www.vhs-france.com/main.php?id=travel&lang=fr) -> [Russian online form](http://visa.kdmid.ru)